# Using a BeanPropertyRowMapper with ResultSet

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, resultset, datamodel

I have a SpringBoot application with a service that retrieves values from a database and passes them to a data model class. At the output, I want to get a list of data models with values from the database.

If I implement the service methods as follows, everything is fine. Here's an example of the method code:

```
public List<DataDto> getData() {
    String sql = "EXAMPLE QUERY";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (resultSet, idx) -> new DataDto(resultSet));
}
```

I would like to implement this using BeanPropertyRowMapper to avoid creating new instances of the DataDto class every time. I write the following code:

```
public List<DataDto> getData() {
    String sql = "EXAMPLE QUERY";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(DataDto.class));
}
```

When I try to execute this code, I get the error: NoSuchMethodException: api.rest.DataDto.().

The DataDto class is defined as follows:

```
@Data
public class DataDto {
    private long param1;
    private long param2;
    private long param3;
   
    public DataDto(ResultSet resultSet) {
        try {
            this.param1 = resultSet.getLong("PARAM_1");
            this.param2 = resultSet.getLong("PARAM_2");
            this.param3 = resultSet.getLong("PARAM_3");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest whether it is possible to implement this using BeanPropertyRowMapper?

I found in the documentation that in DataDto, it is recommended to use a parameterless constructor. However, I specifically need one that takes a ResultSet as input.